# How do I initialize the Core Data's persistent container in AppDelegate and use it throughout the app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate

I'm trying to use `NSPersistentContainer` in a number of view controllers throughout the app for Core Data.

Initially, I had set up the container in a single view controller, which worked fine:

**First View Controller**

```swift
var container: NSPersistentContainer!

container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyCoreData")
container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
    self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

    if let error = error {
        print("Unresolved error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

But, I migrated this code to `AppDelegate` according to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack):

**AppDelegate**

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyCoreData")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let firstVC = window?.rootViewController as? FirstViewController {
            firstVC.container = persistentContainer
        }
        
        if let secondVC = window?.rootViewController as? SecondViewController {
            secondVC.container = persistentContainer
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Each of my view controllers now have a variable called `container` of the `NSPersistentContainer` type. However, when I load the view controllers I get the following error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

This error points towards where `container.viewContext` is.  More specifically:

```swift
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: container.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "title", cacheName: nil)
```

I'm not sure if I'm getting the error from `rootViewController` because I don't have a single root view controller due to the fact that I'm using the Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: You should initialise the persistentContainer once (AppDelegate is fine) and pass a reference to the managedObjectContext throughout your viewControllers. Use that managedObjectContext to access your entities, edit, delete and save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is a <strike>lazy instantiated</strike> computed property in an extension of `UIViewController` and actually you need only the managed object context.

```
extension UIViewController {

    var context : NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

You can also add a `save` function.

Comment: Should I not initialize the persistent container, `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyCoreData")`, and just use `context`? How can I load the persistens stores without the container, like it was done with `container.loadPersistentStores`? Should I put your code within `AppDelegate.swift`?

Comment: Use your **AppDelegate** version and this extension. The property is initialized once and you can use it in all subclasses of `UIViewController`. You can put the code in the `AppDelegate` file or in an extra file `Extensions.swift`

Comment: I'm getting the error `Extensions must not contain stored properties`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it must be a computed property, see the edit.